# `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` in `subprocess.call`

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to apply `subprocess.call` instead of `os.system` following PEP 324

In a task to open multiple urls

```
import subprocess
open_chromes = [
'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embodied_cognition',
'https://docs.python.org/3.6/index.html',
'https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/',]
for chrome in open_chromes:
    cmd = ['open', '-na', 'Google Chrome']
    subprocess.call(cmd.append(chrome))
```

Error reported as

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Alternatively with `os.system` is definitely easy.

```
import os
open_chromes = [
'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embodied_cognition',
'https://docs.python.org/3.6/index.html',
'https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/',]

for chrome in open_chromes:
    os.system('open -na "Google Chrome" {}'.format(chrome))
```

What's the problem with my code?

Comment: `cmd.append(chrome)` does not return anything. it just modifies the `chrome` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `append` function of a list does not return anything, so `subprocess.call(cmd.append(chrome))` is equivalent to `subprocess.call(None)`, which is the problem. You need to append before doing the call

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep it a single line and not changing the original array - use `+` operator

```
subprocess.call(cmd + chrome)
```